# NetworkOnMainThreadException on a service entirely on a different process?

Tags: android, exception, networking, service

I defined a service to my app which I defined with the
android:process=":remote" trait.

That service does all the networking in my app. how is it possible i'm getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

`onStartCommand()` and other call backs runs on the UI thread in a Service. 
Try using the `IntentService`, or any other android multi threading model (`Handler`/`Runnable`/`AsyncTask`).